# Part of string has 1 occurence, part has multiple

Tags: c#, regex

The string source is

```
<?control Alias="QuestionarySuccess" />
<?control Alias="DetailDetail" IsDetail="1" IsReview="1" DetailId="456" EntityID="789" ViewId="123" Style="tyuui" Type="2" BannerId="56" />
```

It can be any count of parameters (such as IsDetail="1", IsReview="1") here (0 or more, any names of parameters). I should find all parameters: there name and values.
I've used such regex:

```
(new Regex("<\\?control( (\\S+)=\"(\\S+)\")+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline)).Matches(template)
```

The problem is: in 2-nd case it finds only last match BannerId="56". What should I do to find all parameters strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered making it in two steps? First you can check if line matches:

```
<?control.*/>
```

and then get each key-value pair with:

```
(?<key>\S+)="(?<value>\S+)"
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. But there will be 2 loops (loop in loop) to get all parameters.

Comment: There always will be two loops as far as I understand - loop through different 'controls' and loop through matched parameters.

Comment: Thanks, Konrad. I think no better decision.